# Using loop on div and data value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, css

I am trying to use loop on div. I already can use loop on retrieving data from DB without a problem. But trying to use that loop on divs too. Because i want to put the data inside a div. So I need to use loop on that divs too. Database's each row for each Divs.

For example:

```
<div class="all-content-wrapper">
    <div class="inside-content-wrapper">
        <div class="inside-photo">
           Photo Retrieving Data Here
        </div>

        <div class="inside-content">
           Building Name
           Company Name
           etc...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use this system for each rows in database.

Here is my database retrieving on view. 
But how can I use it inside a div and also loop the div too for each rows.

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)

            {{$estate->company_name}}
            {{$estate->building_name}}
            {{$estate->address}}
@endforeach
```

Example is like this.

[Booking](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.tr.html?aid=376386&label=bookings-name-lO9ne8CLb_o7ijml9UoG0QS267778037992%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap2%3Aac%3Aap1t1%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atiaud-294889292373%3Akwd-65526620%3Alp1009540%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm&sid=9708d36c13c6d1537016cd34747de9cd&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.tr.html%3Faid%3D376386%3Blabel%3Dbookings-name-lO9ne8CLb_o7ijml9UoG0QS267778037992%253Apl%253Ata%253Ap1%253Ap2%253Aac%253Aap1t1%253Aneg%253Afi%253Atiaud-294889292373%253Akwd-65526620%253Alp1009540%253Ali%253Adec%253Adm%3Bsid%3D9708d36c13c6d1537016cd34747de9cd%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Osaka%2C%20Osaka%20%C4%B0li%2C%20Japonya&checkin_monthday=&checkin_month=&checkin_year=&checkout_monthday=&checkout_month=&checkout_year=&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=osaka&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=tr&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=-240905&dest_type=city&iata=OSA&place_id_lat=34.703966&place_id_lon=135.492927&search_pageview_id=853a3183108500b1&search_selected=true) example is like this:

Comment: Replace `tr,td` with required `div` structure.

Comment: What you need, I believe you would like to change the HTML structure like table layout to Div layout?

Comment: @u_mulder How can I insert the for each loop into `all-content-wrapper` div?

Comment: Same as you already did with table. Please try something, it is not rocket science.

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal sorry, I already delete the td layout.

Comment: @Snickers You have to use the foreach loop anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition to template inheritance and displaying data, Blade also
>   provides convenient shortcuts for common PHP control structures, such
>   as conditional statements and loops. These shortcuts provide a very
>   clean, terse way of working with PHP control structures, while also
>   remaining familiar to their PHP counterparts.

[See more here](https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blade/#control-structures)

That means you can use `@foreach` **anywhere** you want. Even inside `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>` and other html tags.

```
<div class="all-content-wrapper">
    @foreach($estates as $estate)
    <div class="inside-content-wrapper">
        <div class="inside-photo">
           {{ $estate->photo }}
        </div>

        <div class="inside-content">
           {{ $estate->building_name }}
           {{ $estate->company_name }}
           {{ $estate->address }}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Also, you can use any html element you want inside of `@foreach`, `@if` and other blade directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the div inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the div as yo do in table above like

```
@foreach($name as $n){
    <div>{{$n}}</div>
}
@endforeach
```

Div will automatically created for every new value of $n

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)
 <div class="all-content-wrapper">
  <div class="inside-content-wrapper">
    <div class="inside-photo">
       {{$estate->address}}
    </div>

    <div class="inside-content">
       {{$estate->company_name}}
       {{$estate->building_name}}
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```